# Como executar um loop até as linhas de um determinado arquivo.txt acabar

Tags: python

Gostaria de fazer um sisteminha basico com loop por exemplo, abria o arquivo que o usuario digitou depois usava um if para enquanto tiver linhas no arquivo executar um loop com outros codigos

Comment: Pesquise pelo método `readlines` no Python.

Comment: certo vou da uma olhada.

Comment: Na verdade, desde muitas versões atrás, qunado arquivos passaram a ser iteráveis diretametne, usar o `readlines` deixou de ser uma boa idéia:
http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html.

Se quiser uma lista com todas as linhas do arquivo, é possivel passar o arquivo direto para o construtor da lista:   `linhas = list(open("meuarq.txt"))` - sem o readlines,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Python, o próprio objeto que representa um arquivo aberto é feito para funcionar direto com um loop como você fala.
Por exemplo, um programa para imprimir cada linha de um arquivo é simplesmente:

```
nome = input("Digite o nome do arquivo: ")
with open(nome) as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        print(linha)
```

Em outras palavras: você usa o arquivo direto no comando `for` do Python - quando o arquivo acabar ele sai do `for`. (E nesse caso, como temos o `with`, ele saí do `with` também e já fecha o arquivo).

Isso acontece simplesmente por que o objeto arquivo implementa o "iterator protocol" - com os métodos `__iter__` e  `__next__`. Qualquer objeto que tenha esses métodos (implementdos da forma correta) pode funcionar direto no comando `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não gosto de pedir interactivamente nomes de ficheiros;
prefiro a criação de scripts que recebem parâmetros via linha
de comando. Nesso sentido recomendo o módulo `fileinput`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-

import fileinput
for linha in fileinput.input():
   linha=linha.strip()
   #processa linha
```

Deste modo a script funciona como um comando normal Unix, e na linha de
comando podemos dar zero (stdin, pipes) ou mais ficheiros a processar.

Ver também as sempre úteis funções `fileinput.filename()` `close()` `isfirstline()` `lineno()` `filelineno()` `nextfile()`

Comment: Gostei!, e um bom módulo irei usar